# magento 2.3: get CMS page content in template file

Tags: template, magento2.3.2

I want to get CMS page content and title in phtml template file.
How can I get this?

I am trying below code to get content but it's not working -

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$content = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Cms\Model\Page');
$content->load('my_page_identifier', 'identifier');
echo $content->getContent();
```

Please provide a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's wysiwyg editor content. So, you need to use `\Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider` class to filter cms page content and display.

Follow this below code :

> Using construct method

```
protected $_filterProvider;

public function __construct(
    .....
    \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider $filterProvider
    .....
) {
    .....
    $this->_filterProvider = $filterProvider;
    .....
}

public function getContent($identifier)
{
    return $this->_filterProvider->getPageFilter()->filter($this->getPage($identifier)->getContent());
}
```

> Using Object Manager

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$content = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Cms\Model\Page');
$myCmsData = $content->load('my_page_identifier', 'identifier');
$cmsContent = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider')->getPageFilter()->filter($myCmsData->getContent());
echo $cmsContent;
```

Comment: I want to get the content directly in template file using objectManager, don't want to create a custom module..  In above code I don't see a code which loads the cms page using identifier.

Comment: Use my object manager method code in your phtml file.

Comment: Just check my updated answer of object manager method and use in your phtml. Let me know if still not working for you.

Comment: Yes I got the point but I am asking that the how the object manager will load the specific cms page. I don't see any code which is loading through identifier.

Comment: Please check my updated answer.

Comment: I tried the above objectManager code and got the following error - Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Magento\PageBuilder\Plugin\Filter\TemplatePlugin::afterFilter() must be of the type string, null given

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98013/discussion-between-rohan-hapani-and-chanchal).

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code, Hope its work for you...

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$content = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory');
$content->load('my_page_identifier', 'identifier');
echo $content->getContent();
```

Comment: After, $objectManager->create() you don't need to again create object. Please remove last create() method.

Comment: yes,  writing by mistake. :)